# How to debug Behat test with Xdebug in PhpStorm?

Tags: drupal, phpstorm, xdebug, behat, ddev

**Question**:

I'm encountering issues while attempting to debug Behat tests using Xdebug within a Drupal context. Despite setting breakpoints, the debugger isn't stepping into Drupal context functions or my custom co. Here are the details:

**Setup**: I'm running Behat tests for a Drupal project in ddev container.

**Debugger**: Using Xdebug for PHP debugging.

**Issue**: The debugger doesn't step into Drupal context or my custom context, even with breakpoints set in context files.

**Configuration**: Xdebug is configured and, but start from index.php. It seems to skip debugging within Behat tests in a Drupal context, and start debug behavior of website but not context of scenarios.

```
  │ 
  │ __   __   _      _                 
  │ \ \ / /  | |    | |                
  │  \ V / __| | ___| |__  _   _  __ _ 
  │   > < / _` |/ _ \ '_ \| | | |/ _` |
  │  / . \ (_| |  __/ |_) | |_| | (_| |
  │ /_/ \_\__,_|\___|_.__/ \__,_|\__, |
  │                               __/ |
  │                              |___/ 
  │ 
  │ Version => 3.2.1
  │ Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support
  │ 
  │              Enabled Features (through 'xdebug.mode' setting)             
  │ Feature => Enabled/Disabled
  │ Development Helpers => ✘ disabled
  │ Coverage => ✘ disabled
  │ GC Stats => ✘ disabled
  │ Profiler => ✘ disabled
  │ Step Debugger => ✔ enabled
  │ Tracing => ✘ disabled
  │ 
  │                             Optional Features                            
  │ Compressed File Support => no
  │ Clock Source => clock_gettime
  │ 'xdebug://gateway' pseudo-host support => yes
  │ 'xdebug://nameserver' pseudo-host support => yes
  │ Systemd Private Temp Directory => not enabled
  │ 
  │                               Diagnostic Log                              
  │ [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for '172.17.0.1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
  │ [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 172.17.0.1:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
  │ 
  │                               Step Debugging                              
  │ Debugger is not active
  │ 
  │                                    PHP                                   
  │                            Build Configuration                           
  │ Version (Run Time) => 8.2.11
  │ Version (Compile Time) => 8.2.9
  │ Debug Build => no
  │ Thread Safety => disabled
  │                                  Settings                                 
  │ Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.2/cli
  │ Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini
  │ Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d
  │ Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-assert.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-ldap.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-redis.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-uploadprogress.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini,
  │ /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini
  │ 
  │ 
  │ Directive => Local Value => Master Value
  │ xdebug.mode => debug => debug
  │ xdebug.start_with_request => default => default
  │ xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
  │ xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
  │ xdebug.use_compression => 0 => 0
  │ xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.log => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
  │ xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
  │ xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
  │ xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
  │ xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
  │ xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
  │ xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
  │ xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
  │ xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
  │ xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
  │ xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
  │ xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
  │ xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
  │ xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
  │ xdebug.dump_once => On => On
  │ xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
  │ xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
  │ xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
  │ xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.client_host => 172.17.0.1 => 172.17.0.1
  │ xdebug.client_port => 9000 => 9000
  │ xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
  │ xdebug.client_discovery_header => HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR => HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR
  │ xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
  │ xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
  │ xdebug.scream => Off => Off
  │ xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
  │ xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
  │ xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
  │ xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
  │ xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
  │ xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) *"Xdebug is properly configured and works in other scenarios"* Which ones specifically? CLI environment or a web page? 2) Show what you have at `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Xdebug` as well as `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Servers`

Comment: A common problem is not mapping the full project directory. Your project root should be mapped to /var/www/html in Settings->PHP->Servers

Comment: @LazyOne xdebug started from index.php

Comment: *"xdebug started from index.php"* That makes zero added value: `index.php` is just a file and can be debugged in CLI and as a web page. Since I still have no answers to my questions.. I may only suggest the following for now: 1) Ensure that `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Debug | Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations` is disabled (better be safe). 2) Enable Xdebug log and try to debug -- see what it will have there (if it tries to connect to the IDE or does nothing at all).

Comment: @LazyOne, it successfully connects to the localhost website, and all tests run. However, the xdebugger operates through the modules form, but not through the context of browser tests.And I added image link for xdebug and server settings

Comment: 1) Disable the aforementioned `Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations` option -- that's in case your server uses different "name" when doing tests. 2) What Xdebug log has to say when it does not work? Maye Xdebug is not enabled at that point (does not see the "debug me" flag). Will having `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` make any difference? I'm sorry to say that ... but it's hard to suggest much without knowing what you have got there.

Comment: It's possible that your tests might be running as sub-requests and the "debug me" flag is not passed there.... I suggest you put `xdebug_info();` in such a test, save the output of that and show it here -- to see what option it sees at that moment. I'm not doing Drupal development myself so cannot blind-guess what you may be missing in unknown to me environment setup.

Comment: @LazyOne I added output

Comment: So it says that the debugger is not active, but it have tried to connect to `172.17.0.1:9000`.... Can you show the same but when the debug works? Maybe it will show what the difference is (maybe it's trying to connect to another address there etc). No better ideas ATM.